# Why I can't access photo library by using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

[image]there is no error but when i test it on real phone, even in the simulation, it only display a lock image and "This app does not have access to your photos or videos   you can enable access in Privacy settings" but when i turn to setting I couldn't find my app in privacy setting. Where did i go wrong?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false


            let selectedSourceAction = UIAlertController(title: "What source do you want to access?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

            let fromPhotoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
            let fromCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            selectedSourceAction.addAction(fromPhotoLibrary)
            selectedSourceAction.addAction(fromCamera)
            selectedSourceAction.addAction(cancelAction)

            self.presentViewController(selectedSourceAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Go to Settings --> Privacy ---> Photos ---> Enable photos on your app

Comment: @Maddy no, it didn't alert me if I want to decline or accept it access my photo when I first open my app, and I couldn't find my app what just installed in the privacy app list

Comment: @Maddy but I create another project and input the same code, it's work well, I guess it may go wrong on my own project

Answer (score 5):

Such bug may happen on IOS 9 when your application's Info.plist file contains a key: "CFBundleDisplayName" with empty string value.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem after two days of almost going crazy. It's really odd that trying to display UIImagePickerController just fails silently with no indication of what the error is.

Comment: I used TOCropViewcontroller library i am getting pop up in simulator but not on device.any help?